# PHP: How to link the same page for multiple flash games?

Tags: php, html, css, flash

I am making a flash server for my classrooms entertainment during free time and I'm a little confused on how to set it up. I want each link to take the user to the same page for each game but to load the game you clicked on.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["doom.swf"]= "doom";
$_SESSION["pong.swf"]= "pong";
?>
```

I am trying to use sessions but with my code I'm not getting any success.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code that sets the session based on game selection and the code that references the session to load the appropriate game, and let us know what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: I dont have it anymore im not at school anymore

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sessions for this, you can pass the name of the game( .swf file) as a GET parameter.

Let say you have an index.php as your script to present the game, you can pass the game like index.php?game=doom
You could check if the file doom.swf exists, if it does create the page with the doom.swf embebed, if it doesn't exists show an 404.

It should be very simple.

Hope this helps